# My pygame text will not display in my game

Tags: python, pygame

Every time an enemy sprite reaches the end of the screen and disappears, you get 1-3 points depending on what it is. When you get over 100, the game stops, and it's supposed to say in the top left "You win!", but when I run it and win it displays nothing. Here is the code:

```
import pygame, random, time
from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)
print('Use the window above to play')
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
X = 400
Y = 400
play = 1
SCREEN_WIDTH = display_width
SCREEN_HEIGHT = display_height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))


def death():
    print('You died')
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 100)
    textsurface = myfont.render('You Died.', True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))
    print('Score: {}'.format(score))

def win():
    global alive
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 100)
    textsurface = myfont.render('You won!', True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))
    alive = False

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        global play
        if play == 1:
            self.surf = pygame.image.load("Plane.png").convert()
    
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
           self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Missile.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(5, 10)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            global score
            score += 1
            self.kill()

class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bomb, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 25))
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Bomber.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(2, 5)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            global score
            score += 2
            self.kill()

class Blimp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Blimp, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 35))
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Blimp.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 3)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            global score
            score += 3
            self.kill()

ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, random.randrange(600, 1000))

player = Player(display_width // 2, display_height // 2)

enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
bomb = pygame.sprite.Group()
blimp = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

alive = True
while alive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            alive = False
        elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
            new_opponent = random.choice([Enemy(), Bomb(), Blimp()])
            enemies.add(new_opponent)
            all_sprites.add(new_opponent)

    if score > 100:
        print('You won!')
        print('Score: {}'.format(score))
        win()

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    enemies.update()

    screen.fill((50,50,160))

    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()
           alive = False
        death()

    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

and this is where it is supposed to display "you won!"

```
def win():
    global alive
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 100)
    textsurface = myfont.render('You won!', True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))
    alive = False
```

also, here are the images I used

[image: Blimp]

[image: Missile]

[image: Plane]

[image: Bomber]

Comment: You should run. this in a debugger and follow the logic of what's going on.  If the game is playing correctly but just doesn't recognize the end of the game, this should be a pretty easy thing to figure out.  Have you done that at all...run the code in a debbugger?

Comment: `screen.fill((50,50,160))` covers everything that was previously drawn. Hence `win()` has to be called after `screen.fill((50,50,160))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`screen.fill((50,50,160))` covers everything that was previously drawn. Hence  `screen.fill((50,50,160))` has to be done before `win()` is called. I recommend to draw the text on top of the scene:

```py
alive = True
while alive:
    # [...]

    # DELETE
    # if score > 100:
    #    print('You won!')
    #    print('Score: {}'.format(score))
    #    win()

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    enemies.update()

    screen.fill((50,50,160))

    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()
           alive = False
        death()

    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)

    # INSERT
    if score > 100:
        print('You won!')
        print('Score: {}'.format(score))
        win()
    
    pygame.display.flip()
```